# Printing full warning message in tidyr

Tags: r, warnings, tidyr

Is there a way to force a tidyr function to print an entire warning message? I am using the separate function to break a column containing names into distinct columns for the first, middle, and last name. There isn't a consistent structure to this original column and some names require more than 3 columns to fit them. When I use separate I get this:

> Warning messages: 1: Expected 3 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in
> 27 rows [184, 283, 462, 534, 625, 658, 782, 785, 905, 946, 996, 998,
> 999, 1003, 1005, 1350, 1367, 1373, 1374, 1595, ...].

I want to be able to identify those rows so I can manually edit the entries in the new columns created by separate, but the warning message only prints 20 of the 27 rows. I tried using tidylog to get more information but it doesn't contain the separate function. I also tried setting options(warning.length = 2000) and nothing happens. I think it may be because separate is a tidy function, but I can't find any documentation on how to print whole warnings from a tidy function or change the settings for tidy warnings.

Comment: You can use the `extra` argument i.e. `extra = "merge"`

Comment: did you try `warnings()`?

Comment: Didn't know about the merge functionality, thanks for that! 

And warnings() or last.warning() still reports the truncated message. It's not a major issue because I managed to find all the row and fix them, just thought it was weird there isn't a clear way to print the full warning message.